# the percentages or percentage of three different groups

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

In a graph showing data on people using the Internet in Korea, Japan, and China, a writer wrote:

***The line graph compares the **percentage** of people in three countries who used the Internet
between 1999 and 2009.***

The graph shows the percentages in three countries, so I wonder why he didn't use the plural form here.

In a different sample essay, but very similar in question style, he wrote **the participation rates of ...**

Why is his choice of singulars and plurals different from time to time?

Comment: It could be careless inconsistency, or the writer noticed the error in the first, and decided not to repeat it, or it was a typing error.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The thing is, I've actually seen people using both plural and singular in this kind of situation, so it's hard for non-native speakers like me to decide. :<

Comment: You should note that one compares multiple things - you can't compare one percentage, so the plural is definitely required in the case of the description of the graph. You should note that 'sample essays' can be of doubtful quality.

Comment: It's from a native IELTS teacher, so it took me by great surprise to learn that he actually produced wrong sample essays for students. Just to be on the safe side here, could you verify the quality of the following sentences? All are his. By what you said, these should be all wrong.

Comment: 1. The line graph compares the percentage of people in three countries who used the Internet between 1999 and 2009.
2. The line graph compares the percentage of people aged 65 or more in three countries over a period of 100 years.
3. The bar chart shows the percentage of waste that is recycled, put into landfill or incinerated in various EU countries.
4. The table below shows the proportion of different categories of families living in poverty in Australia in 1999.

Comment: Oh wait, I think I've seen the singular form in even IELTS questions themselves, not just in IELTS trainers' samples

Comment: In one of my IELTS questions, it goes "The table below shows the percentage of mobile phones owners using various mobile features."

Comment: You want "The line graph compares the **percentages** of people in three countries who used the Internet between 1999 and 2009"? It helps to be explicit in the question.

Comment: The quotation seems fine to me. Example from [Pew](https://www.pewresearch.org/global/2012/11/26/the-day-after-obama-triumph-sobered-by-unmet-global-expectations/): "the percentage of Germans, French, Spanish and Indonesians expressing positive views of the U.S. increased by at least 25 percentage points". [Population Health Metrics](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4772313/) "The estimated percentage of circumcised males in each country and territory varies considerably." I don't have a detailed grammatical explanation: "fraction"  or "number" could also be used in the singular.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["percentage of population" or "percentages of population" when referring to several countries?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47074/percentage-of-population-or-percentages-of-population-when-referring-to-seve)

Comment: @elliotcm Unfortunately, there are so many different opinions in that thread that I don't know which to follow.